# .net core 2 Format API Response with deep properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am building an application that consists of only an API using .net core 2.1.

I have a parent class (Dad) which owns only a single child (Kid). I am looking for the most efficient way to format the JSON response of my controller; for developers who will integrate my API to their applications.

```
public class Dad
{
    public long Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public Kid OnlyChild {get;set;}
}

public class Kid
{
    public long Id{get;set;}
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public string Useless{get;set;}
}
```

Currently I am doing something like this in the controller:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetDad([FromRoute] long id)
{
    dynamic DadResponse = _context.Dads
        .Where(o => o.Id == id)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Select(p => new
        {
            Dad = p.Name, 
            Kid = string.Format("{0} {1}", p.Kid.FirstName, p.Kid.LastName)
        }).FirstOrDefault();

    return Ok(DadResponse);
}
```

The upside with this approach is that:

1. the resulting DadResponse object has the format I want for my
   API.
2. the resulting MySQL query generated by EF Core will be
   optimized and only select Dad.Name, Kid.FirstName and Kid.LastName.

The downside is that if Kid is null, it will generate an exception.

What is the best way around this; maybe I am using a wrong approach all together. I tried to use JsonIgnore attributes in my models but each of my controllers might need to return slightly different properties (e.g. GET /Kids will return all the kids with their Id, whereas GET /Dads may return only the format described above).

**Update:**
Ideally I would like to have Kid return null value if Dad doesn't have a Kid, but I cannot do something like this:

```
Kid = (Kid == null ? null : string.Format("{0} {1}", p.Kid.FirstName, p.Kid.LastName))
```

I have tried to dynamically update the value after the select, using the following:

```
    dynamic DadResponse = _context.Dads
        .Where(o => o.Id == id)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Select(p => new
        {
            Dad = p.Name, 
            Kid = p.Kid
        }).FirstOrDefault();


        DadResponse.Kid = (DadResponse.Kid == null ? null : string.Format("{0} {1}", DadResponse.Kid.Firstname, DadResponse.Kid.Lastname);

    return Ok(DadResponse);
```

But that throws another exception.

Comment: Have you tried just using the ? operator?  Kid = string.Format("{0} {1}", p.Kid?.FirstName, p.Kid?.LastName

Comment: Yep, it won't compile "An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator"

Comment: In your Startup.cs try to configure NewtonSoft.Json to ingoner nulls settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

Comment: Sorry I just updated the question as it wasn't clear -- I'm looking to return either a default value (null) or the result of string.Format if Kid is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is an EF query that will be translated to SQL. Null propagation can't be translated which is why you get that error.

You don't *have* to format the string in the EF query though, you can load the data you want and use another LINQ to Objects query to map them to their final form. If you load only a single object, you can return a new anonymous type:

For example :

```
var data = _context.Dads
                  .AsNoTracking()
                  .Where(o => o.Id == id)        
                  .Select(p => new {
                          Dad = p.Name, 
                          Kid = new {p.Kid?.FirstName, p.Kid?.LastName}
                       })
                  .FirstOrDefault();
var dadResponse = new {
                          data.Dad,
                          Kid= $"{data.Kid.FirstName} {data.Kid.LastName}"
                      };
return Ok(dadResponse);
```

If you *don't* want to return the `Kid` element at all, you can simply omit it from the result:

```
if (data.Kid.FirstName==null && data.Kid.LastName==null)
{
    return Ok(new {Dad=data.Dad});
}
else 
{
    ...
}
```

Of course, someone could say that since we don't care about the `Kid` property, we could just return the KidFirstName and KidLastName as separate properties, making the code a bit simpler :

```
var data = _context.Dads
                  .AsNoTracking()
                  .Where(o => o.Id == id)        
                  .Select(p => new {
                          Dad = p.Name, 
                          KidFirstName = p.Kid?.FirstName
                          KidLastName =  p.Kid?.LastName
                       })
                  .FirstOrDefault();

if (data.KidFirstName==null && data.KidLastName==null)
{
    return Ok(new {data.Dad});
}
else 
{
    return Ok(new {data.Dad,Kid=$"{data.KidFirstName} {data.KidLastName}");
}
```

Comment: as a former colleague of mine would say: yarg!

Comment: I didn't want to split it using KidFirstName and KidLastName because it would make the JSON response uglier for developers to implement the API. Also if you wish to return a Middle name later, you'd need to change the API documentation and ask developers to re-implement it. First example is exactly what I needed, thanks a lot

Comment: @pab a now famous tweet says [your data model is not your object model is not your resource model is not your message model](https://twitter.com/mamund/status/767212233759657984). Several articles explain why those models should be separate, eg [Web API: Resource Model isn’t your Data Model](https://codeopinion.com/web-api-resource-model-isnt-data-model/) and [Your API and View Models Should Not Reference Domain Models](https://ardalis.com/your-api-and-view-models-should-not-reference-domain-models). If anything, you don't want to change your JSON every time you modify your database or queries